# Как отправить значение из QWidget в QThread?

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, opencv, pyside2

Я пишу небольшую программу с модулями *PyQt5* и *OpenCV*.

Возникла проблема с передачей ширины и высоты `QLabel` в `QThread`.

Программа выглядит так:

```
import sys, cv2, datetime
from CameraDesign import Ui_ScreenshotWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Thread(QThread):
    changePixmap = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.flag = True
        self.cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def run(self):
        while self.flag:
            face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
            ret, img = self.cam.read()
            if ret:
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 10)
                for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                h, w, ch = img.shape
                bytesPerLine = ch * w
                convertToQt = QtGui.QImage(img.data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                scaleRgbImg = convertToQt.scaled(800,500,QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                self.changePixmap.emit(scaleRgbImg)

    def stop(self):
        self.cam.release()
        self.flag = False

class ScreenWin(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_ScreenshotWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.TakeScreenshot.clicked.connect(self.takeScreen)
        self.th = Thread(self)
        self.th.changePixmap.connect(self.setImage)
        self.th.start()

    @pyqtSlot(QImage)
    def setImage(self,image):
        self.ui.CameraLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))

    def closeEvent(self,event):
        self.th.stop()
        self.th.wait()
        super().closeEvent(event)

    def currentTime(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        return str(now.hour)+(":")+str(now.minute)+(":")+str(now.second)+("_")+str(now.year)+(".")+str(now.month)+(".")+str(now.day)

    def takeScreen(self):
        cv2.imshow("screenshot", self.th.cam.read()[1])
        cv2.imwrite('./PhotosForDataBase/'+ self.currentTime() + '.png',self.th.cam.read()[1])

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
myapp = ScreenWin()
myapp.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

В функции `run` строка:

```
scaleRgbImg = convertToQt.scaled(800,500,QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
```

Должна иметь вид:

```
scaleRgbImg = convertToQt.scaled(ScreenWin(self).ui.CameraLabel.width(),ScreenWin(self).ui.CameraLabel.height(),QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
```

Но когда я прописываю в функции инициализации треда такой код

```
self.mainWindow = ScreenWin(self)
self.width = self.mainWindow.ui.CameraLabel.width()
print(self.width)
```

, процесс просто создается, и ничего не происходит. Процесс невозможно закрыть с помощью `Ctrl+C`, возможно только убить его.

Comment: а не работает код потому что у ас получается бесконечный вызов друг друга.
вы из ScreenWin вызываете Thread, а в Thread у вас вызов ScreenWin

Comment: напишите, пожалуйста, как устанавливается модуль ```CameraDesign```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так. Обратите внимание, что я оставил свой путь к файлу `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml`  не забудьте поменять.

```
import sys
import cv2
import datetime
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
#from PyQt5.QtCore import *


#from CameraDesign import Ui_ScreenshotWindow
class Ui_ScreenshotWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, ScreenshotWindow):
        ScreenshotWindow.setObjectName("ScreenshotWindow")
        ScreenshotWindow.resize(800, 500)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(ScreenshotWindow)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.CameraLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(ScreenshotWindow)
        self.CameraLabel.setObjectName("CameraLabel")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.CameraLabel, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.TakeScreenshot = QtWidgets.QPushButton(ScreenshotWindow)
        self.TakeScreenshot.setObjectName("TakeScreenshot")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.TakeScreenshot, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(ScreenshotWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(ScreenshotWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, ScreenshotWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        ScreenshotWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("ScreenshotWindow", "Form"))
        self.CameraLabel.setText(_translate("ScreenshotWindow", "CameraLabel"))
        self.TakeScreenshot.setText(_translate("ScreenshotWindow", "TakeScreenshot"))


class Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    changePixmap = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QImage)

#    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    def __init__(self, width, height, *args, **kwargs):            # + width, height
        super().__init__()
        self.width = width                                         # +
        self.height = height                                       # +
        self.flag = True
        self.cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def run(self):
        while self.flag:
#            face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
            face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(
                'D:/_Qt/Python-Examples/_PyQt5/OpenCV/webcamtest/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
            ret, img = self.cam.read()
            if ret:
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 10)
                for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                h, w, ch = img.shape
                bytesPerLine = ch * w
                convertToQt = QtGui.QImage(img.data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)

#                scaleRgbImg = convertToQt.scaled(800, 500, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                scaleRgbImg = convertToQt.scaled(
                                self.width,                          # + self.width
                                self.height)                         # - , + self.width                  
#                                QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)          # -

                self.changePixmap.emit(scaleRgbImg)

    def stop(self):
        self.cam.release()
        self.flag = False

    def sizeScaled(self, width, height):                             # + 
        self.width = width                                           # +        
        self.height = height                                         # +


class ScreenWin(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_ScreenshotWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.TakeScreenshot.clicked.connect(self.takeScreen)

        self.th = None                                               # +
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10, self.startThread)               # +

    def startThread(self):                                           # +  
#        self.th = Thread(self)
        self.th = Thread(                                            # - self, 
                  self.ui.CameraLabel.width(),                       # +
                  self.ui.CameraLabel.height())                      # +
        self.th.changePixmap.connect(self.setImage)
        self.th.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QImage)
    def setImage(self,image):
        self.ui.CameraLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))

    def closeEvent(self,event):
        self.th.stop()
        self.th.wait()
        super().closeEvent(event)

    def currentTime(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        return str(now.hour)+(":")+str(now.minute)+(":")+str(now.second)+("_")+str(now.year)+(".")+str(now.month)+(".")+str(now.day)

    def takeScreen(self):
        cv2.imshow("screenshot", self.th.cam.read()[1])
        cv2.imwrite('./PhotosForDataBase/'+ self.currentTime() + '.png',self.th.cam.read()[1])

    # можно попробовать увеличить размер окна  или убрать      
    def resizeEvent(self, event): 
        super(ScreenWin, self).resizeEvent(event)
        width = self.ui.CameraLabel.width()           
        height = self.ui.CameraLabel.height() 
        if self.th:
            self.th.sizeScaled(width, height)

if __name__ == "__main__":        
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = ScreenWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

Это должно помочь: передаем значения `width` и `height` в конструктор класса `Thread`

```
import sys, cv2, datetime
from CameraDesign import Ui_ScreenshotWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Thread(QThread):
    changePixmap = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def __init__(self,heigth, width, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.flag = True
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def run(self):
        while self.flag:
            face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
            ret, img = self.cam.read()
            if ret:
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 10)
                for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                h, w, ch = img.shape
                bytesPerLine = ch * w
                convertToQt = QtGui.QImage(img.data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                scaleRgbImg = convertToQt.scaled(self.width,self.height,QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                self.changePixmap.emit(scaleRgbImg)

    def stop(self):
        self.cam.release()
        self.flag = False

class ScreenWin(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_ScreenshotWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.TakeScreenshot.clicked.connect(self.takeScreen)
        self.th = Thread(self, ScreenWin(self).ui.CameraLabel.width(), ScreenWin(self).ui.CameraLabel.height())
        self.th.changePixmap.connect(self.setImage)
        self.th.start()

    @pyqtSlot(QImage)
    def setImage(self,image):
        self.ui.CameraLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))

    def closeEvent(self,event):
        self.th.stop()
        self.th.wait()
        super().closeEvent(event)

    def currentTime(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        return str(now.hour)+(":")+str(now.minute)+(":")+str(now.second)+("_")+str(now.year)+(".")+str(now.month)+(".")+str(now.day)

    def takeScreen(self):
        cv2.imshow("screenshot", self.th.cam.read()[1])
        cv2.imwrite('./PhotosForDataBase/'+ self.currentTime() + '.png',self.th.cam.read()[1])

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
myapp = ScreenWin()
myapp.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```